# Can I use a terracotta pot to bake a pie?

Tags: temperature, pie, utensils

I have cooked many casseroles in a large terracotta pot with great results.  Can I bake a pie in a terracota pot in an electric oven. Can the pot take the high temprature that shortcrust or puff pastry needs?

Comment: Shortcrust doesn't take that high a temperature, 200&deg;C is all you need. In any case we cannot possibly know what temperature your terra cotta pot can take. What temperature have you baked with it before? Is it a pie shaped pan?

Comment: Just to confirm, you are asking about cooking the pie with the terracotta pot as the pie pan, not using a terracotta pot as an oven? (Regarding the former, I have no idea. The latter on the other hand can work fantastically.)

Comment: I assume everything is fine, but I thought I'd comment that red clay cookware has been associated with lead poisoning in the past. You've used the pan before so I'm sure it's fine. Just a random warning for the world.

Comment: I am using my terracotta pot as a pie pan and not an oven.  I have cooked my casseroles at about 170C for about two hours.  I'm a bit concerned that my pie pan will crack if I use it for 200C and above.  kitukwfer, thanks for the warning about the lead I didn't know this!